# Folder links break after reboot

Tags: shortcuts, partitioning

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 onto a drive with existing partitions. I want to make a link/shortcut to one of my games installed on one of the partitions (/media/emily/ Gaming). 
After making a link of the .jar file (FTB.jar) and moving that link to desktop it works. But after restart it says the link is broken and asks me to trash it.

The drive currently says it's mounted. 
Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

I'm very new to linux, so a detailed description of what might be happening and suggestions to fix it would be appreciated.

After restart:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN  RM  SIZE    RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda     8:0      0   298.1G  0   disk
├─sda1  8:1      0   28G     0   part  /
├─sda2  8:2      0   1K      0   part
├─sda3  8:3      0   6.5G    0   part  [SWAP]
├─sda4  8:4      0   65.6G   0   part  /home
├─sda5  8:5      0   100G    0   part
└─sda6  8:6      0   98G     0   part  
sr0     11:0     1   1024M   0   rom

$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2fee48ec-8d63-4125-9eca-5b2e1061602d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=b3804a77-7d80-40a6-8f92-212bed16a151 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=8fff87b8-2128-48ae-bfd4-bc959458f99d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

After making a link from the gaming partition:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup         (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=emily)
/dev/sda5 on /media/emily/ Gaming type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but "/media/emily/ Gaming" indicates to me that you are linking to an external USB drive. Is this correct?

Comment: No. I just have 1 drive with 3 partitions. 1 for Ubuntu, 1 labeled pictures & 1 labeled gaming. However, in order for me to use my drive I had to buy an adapter to convert the drive to Sata. (old IDE hard drive. New computer with Sata only ports)

Comment: and the output of `cat /etc/fstab` please?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm a beginner in Linux.

Comment: open a terminal with CTRL-ALT-T issue the commands requested and copy and paste the output into your question by clicking edit

Comment: bash: cat/etc/fstab: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm not sure of the type. Thank you for your help Jacob. I'll post the results.

Comment: The problem is most likely because the partition is not explicitly mounted, but only gets automatically mounted when you first access it.  If you were to "open" the partition in the file manager, then use the link, it would probably work.  Or, if you were to issue the `mount` command for that partition, it would also work.  You probably should make an entry in `/etc/fstab`, which is not hard at all.

Comment: @MartyFried I searched for a file manager, but don't seem to have one? Could you tell me a step-by-step for your first suggestion? I'm new to linux (only had it for a couple weeks now). Or a step-by-step for mounting that partition. I'm game for either.

Comment: File manager is something like Nautilus.  You must have used it to know where the partition was, and maybe to create the shortcut. When you clicked on the Gaming directory, you used a file manager.  I didn't have time for a detailed answer, and was hoping you might be game to do a little basic research. But to speed things up, do what you did to make the link work, then in a terminal type `mount`.  Tell us what it says, especially anything with "`/media/emily/ Gaming`"  Then, we can determine the type of drive.

Comment: @MartyFried I edited the post above to include the results from running the mount command in the terminal.

Comment: @MartyFried I have tried doing some research on the matter, but coming from a background of Windows XP (of which I could find my way around quite easily), when it comes to Linux - I feel like an idiot & noob. So please bear with me as I try to understand how Linux works. =)

Comment: I understand - I came from many years of Windows, from version 1 to XP, but now I find linux much easier.  I will see if I can give you some help in an answer, which is easier than comments...

Comment: Oh my goodness it worked! Thank you! One last thing before I go? I accidentally added 3 directories, could you help me remove them?

Comment: Their names are 'chown', 'sudo' & 'emily:emily'.

Comment: actual directories (I think?). Look down at Marty's edit and you'll see where I added them by mistake. I believe I added them to my home directory.

Comment: /dev/sda5 /media/emily/DOC ntfs auto

Comment: could you run in a terminal `grep /dev/sda5 /etc/fstab` (mind the spaces)

Comment: /dev/sda5 /media/emily/DOC ntfs auto

Comment: the /dev/sda5 is in red.

Comment: Okay. Done. Do I run that same command but replace 'gaming' with the others? sudo, emily:emily, chown?

Comment: LOL! Thank you so very much! You've been a huge help! And yes, lets remove the many comments =)

Comment: Perfect, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu, partitions may be automatically mounted when you first click on one in Nautilus, and unmounted by right-clicking and selecting "unmount". While it was mounted, you could create a working link, but after restarting, it isn't mounted until you click on it again; then, the link would work.

The solution is to explicitly mount the partition.  This connects it to the filesystem at some directory of your choosing.  So, there are several steps required, but none of them are very complicated, although slightly problematic because of permissions, especially when the partition is formatted as NTFS, which seems to be the case with yours.

For learning, you can use the `mount` command in a terminal, and the `umount` command to unmount.  But in the end, you will want to make a permanent entry in `/etc/fstab`, although there is a method to experiment there, too, using a form of the mount command to tell it to mount everything in the file, and see if you get errors.  If things are not to your liking, you would issue the `umount` command to unmount the new partition, edit the file, then try again.

This is probably not clear, but I'll explain later.

One problem is that I don't have any NTFS partitions, so I can't really tell you exactly what options to use to get the right permissions, which is why I tried not to post an answer, but commented instead.

Now, notice that the mount command gave you a line like this:

```
/dev/sda5 on /media/emily/ Gaming type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

I don't know why there is a space before "Gaming", though.  That looks like an error, but it doesn't matter, as we will create a directory to use.

A...  First of all, you need to create an empty directory to use for mounting, because it needs to exist. So, to keep from getting too confused with the automatic mountpoint, create it under the directory `/mnt`, like so:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/gaming
sudo chown emily:emily /mnt/gaming
```

I'm assuming emily is your username; if not, substitute whatever it is.

B...  Next step is to find a better identifier for the partition. You could use "/dev/sda5", but that's not the most reliable label, because it can change.  I personally use the disk label, for clarity, but most people seem to want to use the UUID, which is assigned at format time, and is always unique.  To find this ID, you would enter `sudo blkid` and look for the line starting with "/dev/sda5".  There should be a section with something like `UUID="nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"`, some combination of numbers and digits.  You will copy that into the fstab file (highlight the big number, copy using shift-ctrl-C, then paste it into the file (later, though).

C... Next, open `/etc/fstab` for editing; I'll assume you will use gedit, but any basic editor is OK.  Enter `gksu gedit /etc/fstab` (because the file is owned by root).  Add a line to the end of the file:

```
UUID=nnnnnnnnnnnnnn /mnt/gaming ntfs-3g defaults,user_xattr 0 0
```

D... Save, but don't close the file.  Go to a terminal, and type `mount -a`.  This will mount everything in `/etc/fstab`, and hopefully will not give any errors. If you get any errors for the line you added, and don't understand the reason, then add a pound sign (#) to the beginning of the line to disable it, save, close, and post back for help.

If it works OK, try finding the directory `/mnt/gaming`, and see if the partition is accessible.  Try creating a link to that directory, and see if it works the way you want.

I hope this will help.  If not, perhaps someone else can do better, as I need to leave for now.

**EDIT**

I tried to add bullets and it messed up some formatting, which I didn't notice because I had to leave in a hurry.  So, 2 lines got unseparated into one, and the result was:

```
 sudo mkdir /mnt/gaming sudo chown emily:emily /mnt/gaming
```

I feel bad about this; what it did was to make more directories than the one - it created `/mnt/gaming`, `sudo`, `chown`, and `emily:emily`, and then tried again to create /mnt/gaming, resulting in the error message.  No real harm done except for some strange directories (owned by root because of sudo).  All of them except `/mnt/gaming` are in whatever directory you were in when you issued the command (maybe your home directory, `/home/emily`).  I will help you delete them when you're ready.  I'm really sorry about that; I didn't initially want to answer because I didn't have enough time, and perhaps it was a mistake to try.

**Edit 2**

When you typed `/mnt/gaming`, The system tried to run a file named "gaming" in the "/mnt" directory.  You need to do `cd /mnt/gaming` and then `ls` to see the files, or use Nautilus to find that directory under the filesystem root directory.

I don't know what the gedit error was, but it may not have been related to anything.  When you typed `sudo mount -a`, it should do nothing if it works; this is the linux way.  If there's an error, it tells you; otherwise it just quietly does what you expect.  So, assuming the partition shows up, it worked.

**Note**

I will keep checking back until solved

Comment: When I tried making an empty directory (sudo mkdir /mnt/gaming sudo chown emily:emily /mnt/gaming) It told me that directory already exists. I continued on and when I typed 'mount -a' nothing happened. So I saved and closed gedit, when I went back to the terminal it gave me this error: (gedit:2556): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
                      I went back and put the # where you said to put it if I got an error, saved it, then closed it.

Comment: I also went ahead and typed '/mnt/gaming' into the terminal and got this: 'bash: /mnt/gaming: Is a directory' any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the formatting when I tried adding bullets.  Please see my edits.

Comment: I think you can probably leave the added line without the '#' in front.  I can't see how that error would be caused by the edit, but perhaps by something to do with gedit (I don't normally use it, I use a different editor).